# Tensorflow variable initialization error

Tags: tensorflow

I am getting the variable initialization error in tensorflow, can someone please help me ? I am using python version(3.5.4) and TF version(1.2.1) on GPU.There seems to be some issue with the gap between the tensorflow and python libraries sync, if I remove the last line from the code then its working fine.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)

    in_size =  100                                                
    h1_size = 10                                                    

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,in_size))                 
    w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size,h1_size]))
    b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([h1_size]))

    xw = tf.matmul(x,w)
    z = tf.add(xw,b)

    a = tf.nn.relu(z)

    yhat = sess.run(a,feed_dict={x:np.random.random([100000,in_size])})



Error:- 

FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Variable_12
     [[Node: Variable_12/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_12"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_12)]]

Caused by op 'Variable_12/read', defined at:
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 245, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 241, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\Users\Sachin-PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your variables before you initialize them. The following code should work:

```
in_size =  100                                                
h1_size = 10    

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,(None,in_size))                 
w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size,h1_size]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.ones([h1_size]))

xw = tf.matmul(x,w)
z = tf.add(xw,b)
a = tf.nn.relu(z)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:    
    sess.run(init)                                                
    yhat = sess.run(a,feed_dict={x:np.random.random([100000,in_size])})
```

Comment: You're very welcome, Sachin. Would you accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left?

Comment: Sure Matt, I did it. I didn't realize it early.